# Array merge and override

Tags: php, arrays

I was wondering if it was possible to merge two arrays and then override the property of the original array.

```
$originalArray = [1,2,3];
$newArray = [
         'first'  => array_merge($originalArray, [4,5]),
         'second' => array_merge($originalArray, [6,7]),
];
```

So what I want to achieve is `$originalArray` would be `[1,2,3]`, then `$newArray['first']` would be `[1,2,3,4,5]` and then `$newArray['second']` would be `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

Right now, what I have is `$originalArray` is `[1,2,3]`, then `$newArray['first']` is `[1,2,3,4,5]` and then `$newArray['second']` is `[1,2,3,6,7]` and that makes perfect sense as `$originalArray` is being merged on both `first` and `second` instance but `$originalArray` is not being overwritten.

I was wondering if that is possible at all? Can we intermediately override the values of `$originalArray` within `$newArray`?

Comment: why don't you perform `array_merge` before assigning it into `$newArray`?

Comment: @AnkitSingh the code above is just an excerpt of what I am working on. So ideally, I dont know if thats possible, but I was thinking if it was possible to do it within `$newArray` itself.

Comment: you want your originalArray values to be same with newArray at the end right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use additional variables to hold the accumulated mergers.

```
$originalArray = [1,2,3];

$newArray = [
    'first' => ($tempArray = array_merge($originalArray, [4,5])),
    'second' => ($tempArray = array_merge($tempArray, [6,7])),
    'third' => ($tempArray = array_merge($tempArray, [8,9])),
    ...
];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was wondering if it is possible to override the value from within the array itself

Comment: Why is that important? Isn't the result what matters?

Comment: Yes, but the code logic that I have is much complex, and I will have to create multiple intermediate variables which I want to avoid.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to put the variable assignment inside the array.

Comment: If you have lots of them, it might be easier to write a function that uses a loop.

Comment: It appears I had a typo when I was assigning the merged value to `$newArray`. Seems `'first' => $tempArray = array_merge($originalArray, [4,5]),` `'second' => $tempArray = array_merge($originalArray, [6,7]),` works fine as well. 
But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Merge as you go with a loop, and update your original array with the last merge.

```
<?php

$orig  = [1,2,3];
$trans = [
         'first'  => [4,5],
         'second' => [6,7],
];

foreach($trans as &$v) {
    $orig = $v = array_merge($orig, $v);
}
unset($v);

var_export($trans);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'first' => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 4,
    4 => 5,
  ),
  'second' => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 4,
    4 => 5,
    5 => 6,
    6 => 7,
  ),
)
```

Comment: This answer seems the most elegant and direct to me.  This is what I'd use in a professional script.  It is the least verbose answer which dynamically accumulates data with each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you want to do:

```
$originalArray = [1,2,3];
$newArray = [
         'first'  => array_merge($originalArray, [4,5]),
         'second' => array_merge($originalArray, [6,7]),
];


function val($newArray) { return $newArray; }
$originalArray = array_map( 'val' , $newArray);
print_r( $originalArray );
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
[first] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 ) 
[second] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 6 [4] => 7 ) 
)
```

Comment: This unexplained answer does not provide the desired result.  This provides the same result as the asker's code.

Answer (score 1):

below will help

```
$originalArray = [1,2,3];


$firstArr = ['first'=> array_merge($originalArray, [4,5])];
$secArr = ['second'=> array_merge($firstArr['first'], [6,7])];
print_r($secArr);
//OR
$newArray = [
         'first'  => array_merge($originalArray, [4,5]),
         'second' => array_merge(array_merge($originalArray,[4,5]), [6,7]),
];
print_r($newArray['second']);
```

Comment: This hardcoded approach is not helpful for the task.  The whole point is to dynamically accumulate values as you iterate.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. It's working for you.

```
<?php
$originalArray = [1,2,3];

$newArray['first'] = array_merge($originalArray, [4,5]);
$newArray['second'] = array_merge($newArray['first'], [6,7]);
$newArray['third'] = array_merge($newArray['second'], [8,9]);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
?>
```

## => Output

```
Array
(
    [first] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
        )

    [second] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
            [5] => 6
            [6] => 7
        )

    [third] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
            [5] => 6
            [6] => 7
            [7] => 8
            [8] => 9
        )

)
```